# OBD GPS device stopped working?

Tags: obd-ii, i20

I own an Indian version i20 and plugged in an OBD device (zyme pro) to track the car. It worked great for 2 days however i went to motor shop for seat covers and reverse camera and suddenly the GPS device stopped working. I am not sure if the mechanic did something or the device went bad. How can i troubleshoot ?

PS: Tried plugging it back few times already.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If they installed a reverse camera, I'd suggest whomever did it, disrupted the feed for the OBD2 device.

Comment: I suspect too, problem is 1)they wont accept 2) i doubt if they would understand it. I will try and keep you folks updated

Comment: When working on cars (or just about anything), when something goes bad, if you've had work done, you can point back to that work and say with complete confidence, *that's probably what did it*. It is ABSOLUTELY the first place you look. If they aren't accepting they did something wrong, then get the reverse camera taken out and get a refund. Also tell them, word of mouth advertising works both ways (good/bad).

Comment: Are there any lights on the device? Does the DLC have power? Some vehicles use the cigaret lighter fuse to run the DLC.